# R markdown error with ggplot2: Object not found

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I have the following R markdown code in my R notebook and the core and plot work well inside the notebook.

`` {r Summary_ADA}
ggplot(Summary_ADA,
       aes(Month, median_ADA), aplha = `School Year`,
       group = `School Year`) +
  geom_point() ``

When I run Knit I get the following error

> Quitting from lines 26-30 (PSD_ADA_Analysis.Rmd) 
>   Error in ggplot(Summary_ADA, aes(Month, median_ADA), aplha = `School Year`,  : 
>    object 'Summary_ADA' not found
>   Calls:  ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> >ggplot
>
> Execution halted

I have Sumarry_ADA on my workspace, and as you can see from the picture below the plot is working inside the notebook. I saw on this thread that knitr operates separately so doesn't have access to things in your workspace, but there was no answer on how to fix it. Any hep is greatly appreciate it

[image: R Notebook plot]

Comment: Knitr creates a new execution envirnment. .All objects defines in the workspace will not be recongnized. You should create a **new chunck** before the plot one , where you define `Summary_ADA`,

Comment: the notebook view is different than the knitted output. the notebook view has access to the workspace data, the knit function generally does not.

Comment: Others have already identified your main problem. One other issue is that `aplha` should be spelt `alpha` and should be included in the `aes`, as should `group`.

Comment: @agstudy- I am confused about what will be the best way to do that? DO I have to save it as a csv and then imported to the notebook or is there a way for me to pull it from my workspace? I created this chunk but get the same error ```{r}
Summary_ADA
```

Comment: @user12081 - the best way is to start from your original data, and then add all of the steps you went through to your .Rmd file, above where you are plotting the results. This way your analysis will be more transparent and reproducible, and will not depend on your current workspace.

Comment: @RichardTelford- thanks!

Comment: @KeithHughitt- Ok that makes sense for the notebook, but what if that is the case for knitting a R markdown document  I might be missing something. I thought Markdow could be used to create reports, but I have to include all my data then what would be the point? I was thought that it was good practice to keep my data cleaning/wrangling separate form my data analysis, but if I dod this then it will require me to do things all in one place. Maybe this is a differnet way of doing thing, and I need to try it our. Thanks so much for your response and explanation